# Load random CSS on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, apache, server-side

I was wondering whats the best way to call a random css file on page refresh with Javascript?

Many thanks

Comment: Does it have to be Javascript? It would be much easier and less kludgy on server side.

Comment: The problem with this is that when your Javascript is run your DOM needs to be complete, thus it is possible the browser has already started rendering the page. Changing the CSS at this point breaks this flow and could slow down page rendering as well as the user to see 'flashes' as the browser changes styles.

Comment: Doesn't have to be javascript, wasn't sure about the doing this server side.

Comment: Server side will be dependent on your server technology. If you update your tags, we can help out a little more.

Comment: `nginx`, `apache`, `ruby`, `php`, `asp` or whatever technolody you use  in the Backend

Comment: Im slightly unsure about doing this server side so may stick to the javascript for the mo, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your advice, didn't realise it was possible with a simple line of php and actually found that this method was pretty short and sweet

```
<link href="/styles/<?php echo mt_rand(1, 5); ?>.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Found it here, http://forum.mamboserver.com/showthread.php?t=61029

Many thanks

ps. A List Apart also have a pretty simple and brilliant way to switch images, http://www.alistapart.com/articles/randomizer/

Answer (score 8):

```
var link = [];
link[0] = "http://site.com/css/style1.css";
link[1] = "http://site.com/css/style2.css";
link[2] = "http://site.com/css/style3.css";


$(function() {
    var style = link[Math.floor(Math.random() * link.length )];
    $('<link />',{
        rel :'stylesheet',
        type:'text/css',
        href: style
    }).appendTo('head');
});
```

**Edit** : Thank you Basil Siddiqui!

```
var link = [];
link[0] = "http://site.com/css/style1.css";
link[1] = "http://site.com/css/style2.css";
link[2] = "http://site.com/css/style3.css";


$(function() {
    var style = link[Math.floor(Math.random() * link.length )];
    if (document.createStyleSheet){
        document.createStyleSheet(style);
    }else{
        $('<link />',{
            rel :'stylesheet',
            type:'text/css',
            href: style
        }).appendTo('head');
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this but it gets applied after the page has loaded so the styling doesn't get applied

Comment: @BasilSiddiqui Thanks for noticing .. please refer to this [tutorial](http://www.vidalquevedo.com/how-to-load-css-stylesheets-dynamically-with-jquery) for further Guidance! Good day! :)

Answer (score 5):

If you're using PHP, you can read your CSS directory and pick a random file like this:

```
<?php
$css_dir = '/css';
$files   = array();

foreach(glob($cssdir.'/*.css') as $file) 
{
    $array[] = $file;
}

echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . array_rand($files, 1) . '">';
?>
```

Comment: Just tried this technique but nothing gets echoed out therefore no CSS file gets loaded

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by generating random link using just javascript

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var r=Math.random();
var x=document.getElementById("demo")
if (r>0.5)
{
x.innerHTML="<a href='http://w3schools.com'>Visit W3Schools</a>";
}
else
{
x.innerHTML="<a href='http://wwf.org'>Visit WWF</a>";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Append a `<link>` element on `document.ready`.

```
var randomFileName=Math.random(); // or whatever

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' + randomFileName + '.css">');
});
```

Untested.  As mentioned above, it is probably a better (read: more compatible) idea for a server-side script to spit out a random file name directly in the page's HTML instead of using JS trickery.

Comment: For other peoples reference - This method adds a random number in the href so its impossible to sync with a css file.

Comment: @Rob: The coming up with a file name part was left as an exercise for the reader. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use javascript the best way is to load all the random styles in a single file in the normal way.

Then prepend all the random css with a number such as:

```
.random-1 h1 {
    color: blue;
}
.random-2 h1 {
    color: red;
}
/* ... etc... */
```

Then simply add a random class to the body with javascript.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].className+=' random-' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
```

This should limit loading and rendering issues, and you don't need to worry about when to call the javascript. (plus you have the option to change to another random style with more javascript)

(Rendering issues will depend on what kind of changes you are making - although this is no different from the hiding and showing of DOM objects you see on many websites.)

Comment: This would also make your server script simpler. Just add a class to the body when you create the page.