# Loading random Stylesheets into a single HTML using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, random

I intend on doing a very simple webpage that changes appearance every time it is loaded. I want to have only one HTML document. It can either be linked to one of several stylesheets (randomly selected), or it can have a single stylesheet with an array of different values.

I would like to use Jquery, since I sort of understand it. PHP or other go a bit beyond my understanding as a front designer in process.

Can I get any help or suggestions? Even being pointed to a direction would help me.

Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: i think you can use Javascript data time function to check time and load particular css.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591488/load-random-css-on-page-refresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple jQuery script:

```
$(function() {
   var items = ['somecss.css', 'somecss2.css', 'somecss3.css'];
   var item = items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)];
   $("head").append("<link rel='stylesheet' href='" + item + "' type='text/css' media='screen'>");
});
```

Where "items" is an array of css styles and "item" is a random style from the array.

Comment: Works great!!! I even thought of doing some sort of SWITCH that added a different class, but since it is such small project, this simple code is awesome!

Thank you so much @kaverzniy

Answer (score 2):

**PHP**

You would have an array of files, and then using the `array_rand` function you can grab a random $files item, based on the index.

```
<?php
    $files = array("file1.css", 
                   "file2.css", 
                   "file3.css"
                   );
    $getRandom = array_rand($files, 1);
?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $files[$getRandom]; ?>">
```

Comment: Hey @Nick R thanks for the answer. I am trying to avoid PHP since I barely understand it. However, I really want to learn. So forgive me being so naive, but I have to add this code in the <head> of my html and save the document as .PHP, ¿right? After that, can I treat the file as a normal index.html?

Comment: @DeividSaenz Yes add it inside the `<head>` tag. To run the `.php` file you will also need a web server, like the WAMP stack if you're on Windows, in order for the PHP to be processed. You can then write standard HTML in your `PHP` file, and enclose any PHP code with `<?php  // code   ?>`